# A snippet not working properly

Tags: python

```
#This program will play a little game

import random

secretnames = ([], [], [], [], [], [])

print('Hi. Please enter your name in letters')
name = str(input())
print('Hi ' + name + '. I am going to play a little game. In this game you have to guess a specific name i am thinking right now.')
print('But do not worry. I am going to let you to enter 6 names and i will choose one of them.')
print('After that you have to answer the correct name that i am thinking right now')
print('Please enter the first name in letters')
secretnames[0].append(input())
print('Please enter the second name in letters')
secretnames[1].append(input())
print('Please enter the third name in letters')
secretnames[2].append(input())
print('Please enter the fourth name in letters')
secretnames[3].append(input())
print('Please enter the fifth name in letters')
secretnames[4].append(input())
print('Please enter the sixth name in letters')
secretnames[5].append(input())
print('Alright ' + name + ' . Thank you for entering the names.')
secret = random.choice(secretnames)
for i in range(10):
        print('Guess a name.')
        ans = str(input())
        if ans == secret:
                print('Good job. You give the correct answer in ' + str(i) + ' guesses.')
        elif ans != secret:
                print('Wrong Answer.')
```

This is the snippet where first you need to enter the names whatever you like and then the program will decide a name from those you have entered and then you have to enter the correct name he is thinking right now. I entered all the names but none of them are working.

Comment: Think about the objects you're working with: `secret` is a single-element list, which will not be equal to the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple.

Your secret variable is a list.
After this line:

```
    secret = random.choice(secretnames)
```

secret is pointing to the list: ['RandomName']

You need to change your if statement like this:

```
    if ans == secret [0]:
      print('Good job. You give the correct answer in ' + str(i) + ' guesses.')
    elif ans != secret[0]:
      print('Wrong Answer.')
```

Answer (score 0):

`secretnames` is a tuple of lists, for some reason. `random.choice(secretnames)` will return one of the sub-lists, which itself contains a single name.

You should just use a single list and append to it:

```
secretnames = []
...
secretnames.append(input())
```